# customView on left button of UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to implement UINavigationBar with custom controls. So, I've added UIView on left side of UINavigationBar and trying to add controls to that UIView with following code:

```
UIView *view = navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.customView;
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];
[button setTitle:@"TEST" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[view addSubview:button];
[button sizeToFit];
[button release];
```

Code works, but button doesn't appear.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

**UPD**

OK, I gave a try to code below and made such thing:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 50)];
[button setTitle:@"XXX" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
navigationController.visibleViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customItem;
[customItem release];
[button release];
```

The "XXX" title did appear, but it looks like simple label, not button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your UIButton doesn't come with any shading. What I've done is used a UISegmentedControl to get shading for free:

```
// Add the Menu button to the navigation bar
NSString* menuLabel = "ShadeButton";
CGSize textSize = [menuLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0]];
UISegmentedControl* menuSegmentedButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, textSize.width, 29.0f)];
menuSegmentedButton.momentary = YES;
menuSegmentedButton.selected = NO;
menuSegmentedButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[menuSegmentedButton insertSegmentWithTitle:menuLabel atIndex:0
                              animated:NO];
[menuSegmentedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doMenu)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
UIBarButtonItem* barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
    initWithCustomView:menuSegmentedButton];
[menuSegmentedButton release];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Create your UIBarButtonItem with the UISegmentedControl as shown above rather than a UIButton and you should get the effect you're after. The alternative is to do more work on the button and create a texture/custom image for it yourself.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try in nearest week and if it works - I'll give you that bounty :)

Comment: Look of button seems differ from standard styles, but it doesn't matter for me - it should be skinned. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Note quite right.

If you just want a different title:

```
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customItem;
[customItem release];
```

If you really want a custom view:

```
// Create Custom View called myView.
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myView];
navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customItem;
[customItem release];
```